# CSS image grid without clear columns

Tags: html, css, grid, masonry

A client asked me to fix their image grid CSS. While I thought they just screwed around to much with the HTML for it to function properly it seems the problem is a bit more technical then I initially thought.

Because I cannot think of the right keywords google isn't much help either.

My problem is this:
[image: problem]
the banners are png's. And as you might figure, the bottom 3x1 banner should align to the bottom of the other 3x1 banner.

This isn't really a problem if I'm working with columns (in this case 2), but I that's not the case. Since sometimes an image takes on a width of multiple columns, there is no clear line in between.

HTML:

```
<div class="page-banners grid-container">
        <div class="grid12-6 banner">
                <img src="3x1.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="grid12-6 banner">
                <img src="3x2.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="grid12-6 banner">
                <img src="3x1.png" />
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid12-6 {
    width: 48%;
}
.grid12-1, .grid12-2, .grid12-3, .grid12-4, .grid12-5, .grid12-6, .grid12-7, .grid12-8, .grid12-9, .grid12-10, .grid12-11, .grid12-12, .grid-full, .grid-col2-sidebar, .grid-col2-main {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
```

Changing

```
float:left;
```

to

```
display:inline-block;
```

doesn't do the trick, it just makes the first 3x1 banner vertically align to the baseline of 3x2.

The answer is probably fairly simple. But I've spend way to much time staring at it.

Below is an example (made in excel) for the page could 'look' like if all the images were inserted. Each color as a placeholder for a banner.
[image: how it should be]

Basically, this is what I want, but without the javascript.
http://desandro.github.io/masonry/demos/basic-multi-column.html

Comment: I think the porblem ist that it's all dynamic and he cannot know at that point if 3x2.png is two rows high or not... as I undestand it.

Answer (score 1):

It should be enough to put the images together into one column, havent tried it

```
<div class="page-banners grid-container">
    <div class="grid12-6 banner">
        <img src="3x1.png" />
        <img src="3x1.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="grid12-6 banner">
        <img src="3x2.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

you might need to adjust the space between them

Comment: The grid has a default of 12 columns (as you might see from the classes) Problem is that within those 12 columns every combination should be possible. There is no clear column break.

Comment: Yes but this case is very similar to bootstrap, it uses basically the same grid system, but there happens the same example: http://jsfiddle.net/ycwuh4f3/ thats because the items float after another, since there is no more space beneath the large without creating a new line/row it has to create one

Comment: That's why I would like to know if there is another way to accomplish this without inline-block or float

Comment: As far as I know: no.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say as you are not giving us the real example of use but try setting the height on the banners as the lowest heigt and the inages will overflow naturaly like so:

```
.banner{height:100px}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/gndLuqqy/

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear what I want to achieve. 
I can set a height for 1 row. 

Also, I can see it works in the fiddle. I don't understand why the larger block doesn't either crop at 100px or just shrinks to fit the 100px height. I guess i've been out of the game for to long...

Comment: Okay, so the img and was given a display:block; in the site, that made it shrink. However after trying to add a row it breaks because the next row continues on 100px.