# CSS - Make multiple divs in columns wrap back around

Tags: html, css

Say I have three divs - Red Green and Blue with the following basic markup and styles: https://jsfiddle.net/ar8sn1o6/

```
<div class="red">Red</div>
<div class="green">Green</div>
<div class="blue">Blue</div>

.red, .green, .blue {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
  width: 48%;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

But I want to be displayed in two column on desktop and one column on mobile like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrMYa.jpg). *Whilst it is reasonably straight forward to have a Red -> Blue -> Green mobile layout, I need to instead have a Red -> Green -> Blue layout*

Is this possible without duplicating any HTML?

Comment: Yep, use `media queries`. See this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Just to be clear the issue is not with media queries. The issue is the flow of the two desktop columns flowing one after the other in a similar vein to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005831/css-image-grid-without-clear-columns

Comment: Than you're question is very unclear.

Comment: Agreed. Added comments for (hopefully) some clarity.

Comment: Check out this updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ar8sn1o6/2/ is that what you want? If so i update my awnser. Thansk

Comment: Ok, i didnt see the updated question. Ill update as soon as ive an awnser to that.

Comment: See updated awnser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using `media queries`

Check out this article to find out more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

> **Syntax**
>
> Media queries consist of an optional media type and can, as of the
>   CSS3 specification, contain zero or more expressions, expressed as
>   media features, which resolve to either true or false. The result of
>   the query is true if the media type specified in the media query
>   matches the type of device the document is being displayed on and all
>   expressions in the media query are true.

*See snippet below. Resize it to see it working!*

```css
.red, .green, .blue {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
  width: 48%;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .red, .green, .blue {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="red">Red</div>
<div class="green">Green</div>
<div class="blue">Blue</div>
```

### UPDATE

What you're trying to achieve is not possible with CSS only.
Ill try to explain why not.

When you style elements with `float: left` or `display: inline-block`. They have an parent element which has the `height` of the highest `child`. So every new block thats inserted on a new row will allign at the bottom of the highest previous child.

So aligning them as you want is not possible. However, you can wrap an `div` around it. And then just add `float: left;` or `display: inline-block`. See this example: **https://jsfiddle.net/ar8sn1o6/2/**

**NOTE:**

> When using float, the parent element will lose its `height`. You can fix this by adding `overflow: hidden` to the parent element.
>
> Or use clearfix. See: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 0):

You could use Media queries to specify certain CSS when the viewport of the device is smaller than a certain/specified size.

For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    container {
        width: 100%;
    }

.blue {
background-color: blue;
width: 90%;
height: 50px;
}

}
```

This would mean that if the width of the device was smaller than 480px, these styles would take effect. I think if you put them all in a container and they all had a width of say 90%, they would align one by one below each other in the mobile view.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Put a container and add media-query

```css
.red, .green, .blue {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1%;

}

.red {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width:100%;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;

}

.blue {
   background: blue;
  height: 50px;
    width:100%;
}

.container, .green{
  float:left;
    width: 48%;
  }
  
  @media only screen 
  and (max-width: 480px)  {
    
    .container, .green{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red">Red</div>
  <div class="blue">Blue</div>
</div>

<div class="green">Green</div>
```

Comment: This is sort of there but I need to have the mobile version to be (from top to bottom) Red -> Green -> Blue rather than Red -> Blue -> Green